# Get data from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import CSV 
with open("statefinancials.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
                line_count += 1
            else:
                print(" rating >=3.00")
```

I have an excel file containing Data

```
     State    Year to date sales       Company Name       Rating
      GA           234333                  xx               2.35
      NV           234333                  xx               4.02
      TX           311122                  kl               3.93
      "            "                         "               "
      etc......
```

I need to get data which is >3.0 rating. Somewhere my code was wrong.

Comment: You are missing a `"` and your identation is way off. please fix. edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
csv_reader = pd.read_csv('statefinancials.csv', delimiter=',')
csv_reader['Rating'] = csv_reader['Rating'].astype(float) # or float64
line_count =  len(csv_reader[csv_reader['Rating']>3.0])
print ("Rows with Rating greater than 3 = ",line_count)
```

Comment: csv_reader['Rating'] = csv_reader['Rating'].astype(Float)
NameError: name 'Float' is not defined

Comment: Code  above looks ok. first your float has a capital letter. You could try 
csv_reader['Rating'] = pd.to_numeric(csv_reader['Rating'] ). that should work

Comment: ValueError: Unable to parse string '12.430444" at position 0

Comment: then remove line `csv_reader['Rating'] = csv_reader['Rating'].astype(float) # or float64` and try again, let me know the error

Comment: I hope you got your answer. Thanks for heads up

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('statefinancials.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    column_names = next(csv_reader)
    index_of_rating = column_names.index('Rating')
    for row in csv_reader:
        # get rating value by using index of rating and compare with 3
        if float(row[index_of_rating]) > 3:
            print('Rating is greater than 3')
```

You can find index of ratings by using index function that is built-in function. After that you need to compare rating value in each row by iterating into rows.

Comment: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: sorry. i fixed it with column_names

Comment: Sorry but this is the problem ' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: you should convet str to float before comparing by using float function 
if float(row[index_of_rating] > 3): ...

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: what is initial type of rating in csv file?. If it is string, reader adds extra quotes to rating value. so rating value turn into " '2.3' ". You should. remove extra qoutes from value. You can do something like float(row[index_of_rating][1:-1])
This means that getting chars between second index  and penultimate index of value.